# How do you buy tiles once you acquire Colonization?

Tags: old-world

1. I have researched **Navigation** which unlocks the **Colonization** law.
2. I have enacted **Colonization** in my empire.
3. **Colonization** allows me to **Buy Tiles.**

How do I actually buy tiles in the UI? I don't see any extra buttons or build orders in the city screen. Is it a **Worker** action? Do I need to end my turn and will be able to do so next turn?

Answer (score 1):

It is a new **Worker** action. Move to the tile you wish to purchase and you'll see a new action, **Colonize (*city name*),** which costs 30 coins (simply called **Money** in the game). The effect is instantaneous, consumes one **Order**, and ends that **Worker's** turn.